# How to get information about an APNS push certificate programmatically?

Tags: java, iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, x509certificate

Is there any java library that enables us to find if the p12 certificate is a proper Apple push certificate?

I use X509Certificate class to check for its validity, but did not find any info about the type of the cert.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "info about the type of the cert"?

Comment: As I said, I just want to verify if it is an APNS push certificate without attempting to make an actual push.

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143646/validate-x509-certificates-using-java-apis and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059196/accepting-certificates-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if an APNS certificate can actually be distinguished from any other certificate.

However, to check the *authenticity* of a given certificate, that is, to verify it is trustworthy, its *certificate chain* needs to be inspected to make sure that it contains a kown, trusted certificate. This usually is one issued by a [Certificate Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).

In the case of the APNS, according to [this](http://www.24100.net/2010/12/latest-apple-push-notification-certificate-changes-decrypted/) source and the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html), a certificate from the "Entrust Secure CA" is required to be in the chain. This certificate is supposed to be 'well-known' and can (with a possible minor degradation of long-term security) usually be regarded as a constant during the lifetime of an application; your application can then just compare its *known* certificate to the one present in the keychain of the certificate in question.

And finally: The crypto library from [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) is the de-facto standard implementation of extended crypto functionality for Java and can also be used to inspect and/or [validate certificates](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/12/01/x509-certificate-validation-in-java-build-and-verify-chain-and-verify-clr-with-bouncy-castle/) and their signatures.

Comment: I would appreciate some java code to help inspect the certificate chain.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `CertificateVerifier` class in the [link](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/12/01/x509-certificate-validation-in-java-build-and-verify-chain-and-verify-clr-with-bouncy-castle/) I included? - That should be pretty much all that's needed. Or am I missing something?