# Azure IDP metadata loading fails

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I am working on a project that re-uses https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample to integrate with Azure AD as IDP.

The integration went pretty smoothly. The only thing I couldn't fix was metadata trust check.

According to https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html
it's recommended to set metadataTrustCheck to false to skip signature validation

However, I'd like to ask if it's possible to use metadata trust check with Azure.

To recreate, set IDP metadata url to 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/sample.onmicrosoft.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

set metadataTrustCheck to true for `WebSecurityConfig#extendedMetadataProvider`

and import login.microsoftonline.com SSL cert into samlKeystore.jks

```
2018-01-23 09:58:05.450 DEBUG 9924 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.o.xml.signature.SignatureValidator     : Signature validated with key from supplied credential
2018-01-23 09:58:05.451 DEBUG 9924 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.o.x.s.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine    : Signature validation using candidate credential was successful
2018-01-23 09:58:05.451 DEBUG 9924 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.o.x.s.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine    : Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential
2018-01-23 09:58:05.452 DEBUG 9924 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.o.x.s.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine    : Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
2018-01-23 09:58:05.452 DEBUG 9924 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.x.s.x.BasicX509CredentialNameEvaluator : Supplied trusted names are null or empty, skipping name evaluation
2018-01-23 09:58:05.452 DEBUG 9924 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.s.s.t.MetadataCredentialResolver     : Attempting PKIX path validation on untrusted credential: [subjectName='CN=accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net']
2018-01-23 09:58:05.458 TRACE 9924 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.s.s.t.MetadataCredentialResolver     : Building certificate path using default security provider
2018-01-23 09:58:05.466 TRACE 9924 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.s.s.t.MetadataCredentialResolver     : PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential: [subjectName='CN=accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net']

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.CertPathPKIXTrustEvaluator.validate(CertPathPKIXTrustEvaluator.java:85) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.3.RELEASE]
```

The issue doesn't happen with ssocircle metadata https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml

Answer (score 0):

The certificate used to sign your metadata seems different from the one at login.microsoftonline.com which you imported.

See [Signature trust establishment failed for SAML metadata entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363676/signature-trust-establishment-failed-for-saml-metadata-entry)